# Symfony 3.3 Unable to find the controller for path "/login/check". The route is wrongly configured

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication

I know there were some questions already asked although after checking 20x if it's not the same case as others had still I have no solution for my case yet.

I've set up my own authentication listener. No matter if it stores the Token or not (return null while handling) I'm getting the same error message. Have no clue what's wrong as the **/login/check** path is behind main firewall see the **security.yml**:

```
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        zwzt:
            provider: in_memory
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: /login
```

my **routing.yml** file:

```
logout:
    path:   /logout

login_check:
    path:   /login/check
```

any ideas what's wrong here?

some logs as requested:

```
[2017-08-30 12:44:39] request.INFO: Matched route "login_check". {"route":"login_check","route_parameters":{"_route":"login_check"},"request_uri":"http://localhost/login/check","method":"POST"} []
[2017-08-30 12:44:39] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2017-08-30 12:44:39] request.WARNING: Unable to look for the controller as the "_controller" parameter is missing. [] []
[2017-08-30 12:44:39] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "Unable to find the controller for path "/login/check". The route is wrongly configured." at /var/www/v2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 137 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): Unable to find the controller for path \"/login/check\". The route is wrongly configured. at /var/www/v2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:137)"} []
```

Comment: Is zwzt supposed to be a firewall?

Comment: Can you show what's written to your log file when you try to log in?

Comment: @Cerad yes - zwzt is my custom Auth "handler"

Comment: @xabbuh - I've added them to question

Comment: Okay.  The indentation sure looks funny.  Is this a guard based authentication system?  Are you following any particular guide?  Does your handler get called?

Comment: well, it does say, it doesn't know which controller to call ...

Comment: I don't use Guard as I thought to write custom auth provider according to (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html). I think I know what's wrong in here. As there is no handler that supports the request and none of them return Redirection HttpKernel expects to hit the controller which is not set in routing and that cause the issue. Seems that every time when you set custom login_check path you need to "assign" handler to it and make sure it either deny access or redirect to failure/success path.

Answer (score 0):

You might need configure the default `_controller` for custom `check_path` and `logout.path` although this will never be executed. Symfony will intercept this first and handle the logout automatically:

```
public function logoutAction()
{
    throw new \Exception('This should never be reached!');
}
```

Same for `check_path` controller, but as a trick, you can configure the same path that `login_path` without do anymore.

Comment: Was trying to do so already and unfortunately I reached the controller which is unexpected behaviour. The reason is that all listeners are called before dispatching to controller. If no response found in the event then the corresponding controller is reached...